# AWS Lambda Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

recently I was using aws along with lambda function to work on my files on S3. Sadly after uploading my zipped NodeJS code using claudia, I still receive Error: spawn EACCES while processing and saving my files back on S3. The same thing appears after uploading using aws console. My buckets have configured policies to allow getting and putting objects. Also lambda has IAM Role and has full access to bucket.

Does someone have any idea, what can possibly go wrong? I'm working on Windows.

Thank you

Comment: Make sure you are saving file in /tmp in AWS Lambda. Can you share the code that is doing saving and uploading. "Error: spawn EACCES" is node error, not AWS, so it's not related to the roles.

Comment: Please post your `exports.handler` code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the command 010_add_platform_class.js missing execute permission.

You could use chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js to give execute permission.

I found this solution on the Ionic framework forum at the below link. http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-fix-this-error-spawn-eacces/20490/6

Comment: I don't have this file in my source, also I don't know if windows has an equivalent form chmod.

Comment: it is something related to permissions only